# Check if user is admin when loggin in

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm learning PHP and I found an article about logging in, which I wanted to apply to my small database.

[Article](http://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/)

I've got it all up and running, but I want to have a different layout for when an theoretical admin, in this case me, logs in. My data is basically a list of random things, and when the admin logs in, there has to be delete button next to said random things.

The users table looks like this:

```
Username | Password   | Rights

SomeGuy  | somestuff  | Standard

Admin    | otherstuff | Admin
```

I've tried learning from some other questions I found online, but those codes were really advanced and I didn't understand how to apply it to my own code.

What I had in mind:

```
if(username contains "Admin" in the row){
    //Show other stuff then normal user
}
```

If anybody knows an easy way to accomplish this, I'd appreciate it a lot.
As for my code, I got mostly everything from the article I linked. I only added a way to display the data from another table.

Comment: `select * from users where username='Admin'`, fetch the row, then check if the rights field contains the appropriate word...

Comment: will you show us the code you have done so far?

Comment: @MarcB But how do I turn that into an `if else` statement?

Comment: That article looks to be a little outdated. The `mysql_*` functions in PHP have been [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).  I would suggest starting to learn working with databases _first_, and use either [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) for fetching records from the database.

Comment: Do you know anything about `mysqli` or `PDO`? just like @watcher said. You should't use `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: you write it? `if($row['rights'] == 'Admin' ) { do admin stuff } else { don't do admin stuff}`

Comment: @akar I've learned some from a friend. I mostly learn from try and error.

Comment: Oh, so you should learn more. learn the PDO. learn to fetch stuff from database and then go on into advanced topics. like authentication.

Comment: @MarcB I figured out what that's doing. But that code isn't working for me.

Comment: then you need to show the actual code that's not working. we can't help you otherwise.

Comment: @MarcB I send a link to the article which is basicly everyting I got so far. I only added a small bit to fetch data from the list of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this by fetching the data from table on the basis of username and than you can check the rights of that user.

Like this:

```
if($row['Rights'] == 'Admin'){
    //Show other stuff then normal user
}
```

You can use `Select * FROM table where username = 'Admin'` and then create the the object of query result and you can check the rights given to that user in if condition.

**Updated:**

In the documentation there is a file `login.php`. there is code line:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'", $connection);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username; 
header("location: profile.php");
}
```

In the above line they set the usename in session. you can set the rights of user also. To store the rights you can do this:

```
if ($rows == 1) {
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$_SESSION['login_user']=$row['username'];
$_SESSION['rights']=$row['rights'];
header("location: profile.php"); 
}
```

And after that you can make a check condition where you want:

```
if($_SESSION['rights'] == 'Admin'){
    //Show other stuff then normal user
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I read about `select * from table where username = 'admin'` on multiple stackoverflow posts, but I don't know how to work that into a `if-else statement`.

Comment: @Vasco I have updated my answer on the basis of article. check that plz.

Comment: Isn't `'username'` inside `$_SESSION['login_user']=$row['username'];` the text you put into the input field in the login screen? I don't fill in that I'm an admin so how would `$_SESSION['rights']=$row['rights'];` work?

Comment: @Vasco when you put the text to login with admin credential then it will go to login.php page where it will check the credential and fetch the information of the admin section and that time it will put the rights in the session.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to store all shared user data in a session after logging in as said before.

When the user submits his login request, your script should validate the given input *(username, password in your case I assume)* and after the validation has succed, you will have to create a session so the system will know that this user is currently logged in.

Session allows you to share data for a client for X time (depending on the set configuration) without the data being lost. It's really similar to Cookies, but the data is server sided istead.

In your case, I'd save the username, his rights and so on in the session.

**The validation part**

```
//Assuming you have a set PDO instance
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT username, rights FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
$stm->execute(array(":username" => $username, ":password" => $password));
```

**And the setting part**

```
 if ($stm->rowCount() == 1) { // Check if that user with given data exists
      $results = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Fetch the data
      $_SESSION['user'] = $results; // Set new session with the fetched data
 }
```

**And now the checking for rights part**

```
if ($_SESSION['user']['rights'] == 'Admin') {
    // TODO stuff
}
```

Don't forget to check if user is logged in by checking if the session is set:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
   // TODO return to logged in page or whatever
}
```

**P.S I suggest you to hash passwords before being stored in the database!**
Hope that helped!